# Select MAX for multiple criteria in a group

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Apologies if this has been answered, I'm new enough that I didn't even know how to search:

I have one table:

> ### Lot      SKU   Cost   Date
>
> 1001-1   1001  .30    10-12-14
>   1001-2   1001  .33    10-19-14
>   1001-3   1001  .32    11-20-14
>   1002-1   1002  .45    10-12-14
>   1002-2   1002  .45    10-19-14
>   1002-3   1002  .44    12-01-14
>   1003-1   1003  .12    10-15-14
>   1003-2   1003  .13    10-19-14
>   1003-3   1003  .10    11-23-14

i need to sum the cost of the oldest row for each SKU.

expected outcome:  (.30 + .45 + .12) = .87

is this possible through one query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL support a function called `row_number()`, which can be very helpful for this type of query.  The following is how you would use it in this case:

```
select sum(cost)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by sku order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The question is tagged [access-vba]; Access doesn't support ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @ZevSpitz . . . That tag appears to have been added a day after I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select sum(t.cost)
from some_table t
join ( select sku ,
              min(some_datetime_column) oldest
       from some_table
       and some_datetime_column is not null
       group by sku
     ) s on s.sku    = t.sku
        and s.oldest = t.some_datetime_column
```